# Problema de directiva estructural angular 9 con jhipster

Tags: angular, angular-directivas, angular9

Tengo problemas creando una directiva en angular 9.
Mi proyecto fue creado inicialmente con jhipster
De resto angular 9, node 14, bootstrap.

El caso es que las directivas que se crearon al inicio del proyecto funcionan, pero si creo una nueva directiva siempre me arroja que la *directiva X since it isn't a known property of 'p'* (No es una propiedad conocida de la etiqueta html P). Normalmente este error es que simplemente hay que agregar el componente/directiva a un modulo, pero en este caso el mismo ng serve lo hace (probe hacer todo manual y tengo el mismo error)

Pensé que se trataba del código en mi directiva, pero usando la documentación de angular https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives con el mismo código de la documentación el error es el mismo.

Este es el código de la directiva que ofrece angular en su documentación:

```js
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Add the template content to the DOM unless the condition is true.
 */
@Directive({ selector: '[jhiUnless]'})
export class UnlessDirective {
  private hasView = false;

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) { }

  @Input() set jhiUnless(condition: boolean) {
    if (!condition && !this.hasView) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
      this.hasView = true;
    } else if (condition && this.hasView) {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
      this.hasView = false;
    }
  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bajo y subo el proyecto pero nada. Parece que al hacer el npm start no compila las nuevas directivas. Habrá una forma de forzar a que compile esas nuevas directivas, o alguna idea de que puedo hacer para resolverlo?

Comment: Es posible que la directiva este importada pero no exportada, asi que es bueno que verifiques.

Comment: Gracias!, Encontré el error. Angular está llamando al set del input @Input() set jhiUnles al hacer la compilación.

Cuando creas una directiva que lo hice con el cli (ng g d unless) como el ejemplo de la doc de angular, jhipster metió la mano y convierte el selector en jhiUnless pero en los métodos seguía llamando a unless en lugar de jhiUnless, lo loco fue que lo escribí bien aquí y en mi entorno no. Me tomó horas darme cuenta, pero con mi directiva real que estaba haciendo pasaba lo mismo, no la estaba nombrando correctamente. Debido al jhi que arregla jhipster https://www.jhipster.tech/

Answer (score 1):

Encontré el error. Angular está llamando al set del input @Input() set jhiUnles al hacer la compilación. Cuando creas una directiva que lo hice con el cli (ng g d unless) como el ejemplo de la doc de angular, jhipster metió la mano y convierte el selector en jhiUnless pero en los métodos seguía llamando a unless en lugar de jhiUnless, lo loco fue que lo escribí bien aquí y en mi entorno no. Me tomó horas darme cuenta, pero con mi directiva real que estaba haciendo pasaba lo mismo, no la estaba nombrando correctamente. Debido al jhi que agrega jhipster.tech